# Vagrant - Provisioning script not changing directory

Tags: shell, vagrant, provisioning

New to vagrant, please help!

**Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vm-setup/provision.sh"
end
```

**vm-setup/provision.sh**

```
# Update apt-get
apt-get -y update

# Install tree
apt-get install tree

# Create .bash_aliases
sudo echo 'alias cls="clear"' >> ~/.bash_aliases

sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) vagrant

cd /vagrant
```

provision.sh file runs fine. When I run "vagrant provision" it updates apt-get, installs tree and even changes the shell to ZSH.

But `sudo echo 'alias cls="clear"' >> ~/.bash_aliases` and `cd /vagrant` lines do not work, not sure why. When I `vagrant ssh` into the machine, I am being taken to root directory (`/home/vagrant`). I would like to start in `/vagrant` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vagrant's shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) by default runs with `privileged = true`:

> privileged (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script
>   as a privileged user or not (sudo). By default this is "true".

When you perform `vagrant ssh` you login to a VM as `vagrant` user.

That's why:

**1.**

> ```
> # Create .bash_aliases
> sudo echo 'alias cls="clear"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
> ```

It writes to `root's` ~/.bash_aliases and it is really there:

```
root@vagrant:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@vagrant:~# cat .bash_aliases 
alias cls="clear"
```

**Solution:** write to `vagrant's` home folder:

```
# Create .bash_aliases
echo 'alias cls="clear"' >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
```

**2.**

> ```
> cd /vagrant
> ```

This means that folder was changed in provision script, nothing else.

**Solution:** add this statement to `vagrant's` `.bash_aliases` as well:

```
echo 'cd vagrant' >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
```

Your final `vm-setup/provision.sh` is:

```
# Update apt-get
apt-get -y update

# Install tree
apt-get install tree

# Create .bash_aliases
echo 'alias cls="clear"' >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
echo 'cd /vagrant' >> /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases
chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases

chsh -s $(which zsh) vagrant
```

Comment: You are the best! It works and awesome explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

Even not being the case, just for the sake of completion:

I had struggled many times while trying to use Vagrant as testing tool for setup scripts and just now I realized the underlying reason:

Using this Vagrantfile statement:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "myScript.sh"
```

`myScript.sh` is *inlined* to the virtual machine standard input. This is good in the sense you don't need access to the actual script from inside the virtual machine (typically through `/vagrant` path).

...but it comes with the drawback that any relative path won't work properly.

> Of course: We can adjust it to absolute path based on `/vagrant`. But this requires to modify the script we are trying to test.

So in this case (and in my opinion in any case we are not going to disable `/vagrant` share), it is a better solution to use "inline:" option with the "machine-internal" path:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/vagrant/myScript.sh"
```

...This will *inline* this statement instead of the contents of the file and relative paths (or even "script path based" ones such as `$(dirname "${0}")/relative/path`) are going to work properly.

Additionally, if the setup script you are going to test is intended to be executed by non privileged users (for example if it is going to set up some user configuration we will expect to work just after a `vagrant ssh` -with vagrant user-) it is also a good idea to add the `privileged: false` option, pointed out by @Nickolay:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/vagrant/myScript.sh", privileged: false
```